# First time connection Oracle Sql Developer to Express database: ORA - 2800 - The acct is locked

Tags: oracle11g

I've installed the Oracle 11g express then the Oracle Sql Developer. Now, I'm trying to connect both as the Oracle website says (usename and password are both **hr**), but I'm getting an error (see screenshot).

[image]

I've tried other roles besides default, but I'm getting either **the account is locked** or **not enough privileges**.

I'm stuck. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

By default, the "standard" accounts (like HR) are locked after installation. You must log in as  **SYS as SYSDBA** and unlock them.

If you are using SQL Developer, you can do this by connecting as SYS (I assume you created a connection, if not you should create it; make sure to use the `SYSDBA` role in connection properties). Once logged in as SYS with the SYSDBA privilege, on the left in the Connections pane expand the SYS node (click on the + sign next to it). At the bottom of the list that opens up, find the `Other Users` node. Expand it and right-click on `HR`. Select `Edit User`, and on the `User` tab of the pop-up window, uncheck the box next to "Account is Locked".

[image]

Comment: So different from sql server. I've tried Username: `sys` and Pwd: `sys`, and Role: `SYSDBA`. I got an error: `invalid username/password.`

Comment: I've tried also `SYS` uppercase for username/password, still getting the same error.

Comment: ?? You are getting the error that `SYS` is locked? I don't believe you. How did you manage to do that?

Comment: And, to clarify - yes, you can "lock the `SYS` account" - but even that doesn't prevent you from logging as `SYS AS SYSDBA`.

Comment: @Richard77 - So - how did you lock `SYS`? Or was that not true when you said it? I didn't see anything about that in the YouTube piece.

Answer (score 0):

Please login to command line - sqlplus

Login as the user 'system'

Type -- alter user hr identified by "password" account unlock;

"password" should be the new password

Login with the new password.